# How to call a C++ method using v8 engine

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm embedding JavaScript into a C++ application using V8 as JS engine. I want to call C++ methods using JavaScript. For example:

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x_, y_;
    Point(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
    void setX() {
        x_ = x_ + y_;
    }

};
```

I want to be able to call the `setX()` function using JS without change the method in C++. Is that possible? Can you show how that would work with the above code?

Comment: You need to expose that method to your node runtime. [Official Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) deal with that. You might need to introduce a wrapper type over that class to use it, though.

Comment: Wish my PC used a V8 engine ... or that I could afford it if it did